# jquery: name change of cloned object not working in IE?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Via jQuery I'm dynamically cloning an input checkbox object, and then I'm changing its name using this instruction:

```
row.find('[name="ACCCHB_CDARM"]').attr("name",id);
```

`ACCCHB_CDARM` is the attribute's name of object I'm cloning.

There's no problem using FireFox, but in IE it doesn't change the original value!

Is this code correct?

Thank you very much.
Mirco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your error, I've written the following code, which works just fine with Internet Explorer 8.0:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var row = $('#row');
        var inp = row.find('[name="ACCCHB_CDARM"]');
        inp.attr("name","NewName");
        alert(inp.attr("name"));
    });
</script>
<div id="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ACCCHB_CDARM" />
</div>
```

`NewValue` is alerted after changing the `name` attribute to `NewValue`.

It looks like that on older versions of Internet Explorer, the [`name` attribute couldn't be changed dynamically](http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2005/05/23/setting-the-name-attribute-in-internet-explorer/) (the post dates back from the year 2005). The [current MSDN documentation for `name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184(VS.85).aspx) states the following:

> Microsoft JScript allows the name to
>   be changed at run time

Further down in the documentation, where some examples are shown on how to dynamically change the `name` attribute you'll find the following line:

> This feature requires **Windows Internet Explorer 7 or later**

To bring my answer to the point, it looks like you're using an older version of Internet Explorer.